# How to get the min, max and sum of all columns in the database?

Tags: loops, if-statement, plsql

I am trying to get the min, max and sum of all columns in the database, but I am stuck on an error. I am trying to insert into a table the min and max if data_type column in `('VARCHAR2','TIMESTAMP(6)','CHAR','DATE','INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9)','INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)')` 
and if it is a 'Number' to calculate the sum, if neither of both, it should write '###'

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COMPARAISON_TEST AS 
BEGIN
declare

cursor c_tab is

select all_tab_cols.owner
, all_tab_cols.table_name
, all_tab_cols.column_name
, all_tab_cols.data_type
, all_tables.num_rows
from all_tab_cols 
left join all_tables on 
all_tab_cols.table_name = all_tables.table_name
where all_tab_cols.data_type in ('VARCHAR2','TIMESTAMP(6)','CHAR','DATE','INTERVAL DAY(9) TO 
SECOND(9)','INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)','NUMBER')
and all_tab_cols.table_name not like '\_%' escape '\' 
and all_tab_cols.owner in ('ODS','DWH','DQM','SCL','STG')
and all_tables.num_rows not in ('0');

v_sql VARCHAR2 (300);
v_val VARCHAR2 (300);
v_sqln VARCHAR2 (300);
v_valn VARCHAR2 (300);
v_sqls VARCHAR2 (300);
v_vals VARCHAR2 (300);

dat_situ date;

begin
dat_situ := current_date;

for r_tab in c_tab loop

if r_tab.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' and 
all_tab_cols.data_type = 'TIMESTAMP(6)' and
all_tab_cols.data_type = 'CHAR' and
all_tab_cols.data_type = 'DATE' and
all_tab_cols.data_type = 'INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9)' and
all_tab_cols.data_type = 'INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)'
then

v_sql := 'select max('||r_tab.column_name||') from '||r_tab.owner||'.'||r_tab.table_name;
v_sqln := 'select min('||r_tab.column_name||') from '||r_tab.owner||'.'||r_tab.table_name;

else if all_tab_cols.data_type = 'NUMBER'
then

v_sqls := 'select sum('||r_tab.column_name||') from '||r_tab.owner||'.'||r_tab.table_name;
else

v_sql := '###';
v_sqln := '###';
v_sqls := '###';


execute immediate v_sql into v_val;
execute immediate v_sqln into v_valn;
execute immediate v_sqls into v_vals;

DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(buffer_size => null);
dbms_output.put_line(r_tab.owner||' : '||r_tab.table_name||' : '||r_tab.column_name||' : '|| v_val||' : '||v_valn||' : '||v_vals||' : '||dat_situ||' : '||r_tab.num_rows);

insert into MOE_COLMINMAX (owner,table_name,column_name,column_max,column_min,dat_situ,num_rows)
values (r_tab.owner,r_tab.table_name,r_tab.column_name,v_val,v_valn,dat_situ,r_tab.num_rows);
commit;
end if;
end loop;
end;
END COMPARAISON_TEST;

ERRORS 
Erreur(67,5): PLS-00103: Symbole "LOOP" rencontré à la place d'un des symboles suivants :     if 
Erreur(69,5): PLS-00103: Symbole "COMPARAISON_TEST" rencontré à la place d'un des symboles suivants :     ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all good, i made it out
here is the code to whom may need it

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COMPARAISON_TEST_MINMAX AS 
BEGIN
declare
--                          cursor pour l'ecriture des MIN MAX pour toute les cahmps 
de toute les tables de la base de donnée
--                          recupération des nom des tables et leurs nom des colonns
--                          filtrage par type de données -- fuire la tiret bas qui 
existe au debut du quelque nom de tables
cursor c_tab is
select all_tab_cols.owner
 , all_tab_cols.table_name
 , all_tab_cols.column_name
 , all_tab_cols.data_type
 , all_tables.num_rows
from all_tab_cols 
left join all_tables on 
all_tab_cols.table_name = all_tables.table_name
where all_tab_cols.data_type in ('VARCHAR2','TIMESTAMP(6)','CHAR','DATE','INTERVAL         
DAY(9) TO SECOND(9)','INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)','NUMBER','DECIMAL','DOUBLE')
and all_tab_cols.table_name not like '\_%' escape '\' 
and all_tab_cols.owner in ('ODS','DWH','DQM','SCL','STG')
and all_tables.num_rows not in ('0');
--                          1er variable v_sql pour enregistrer la valeur maximale des colonnes
--                          2eme variable v_val pour recuperer la valeur de variable v_sql
--                          3eme variable v_sqln pour enregistrer la valeur minimale des colonnes
--                          4eme variable v_valn pour recuperer la valeur de variable v_sqln
--                          5eme variable v_sqls pour enregistrer la valeur somme des colonnes
--                          6eme variable v_valn pour recuperer la valeur de somme v_sqln
--                          7eme variable v_sqls pour enregistrer la valeur count des colonnes
--                          8eme variable v_valn pour recuperer la valeur de count v_sqln
v_sql VARCHAR2 (300);
v_val VARCHAR2 (300);
v_sqln VARCHAR2 (300);
v_valn VARCHAR2 (300);
v_sqls VARCHAR2 (300);
v_vals VARCHAR2 (300);
v_sqlz VARCHAR2 (300);
v_valz VARCHAR2 (300);
--                          definir dat_situ qui prend la date de lexecution de ce code
dat_situ date;
begin
dat_situ := current_date;
--                          une boucle pour passer par toutes les colonnes de toutes les table de base de donnée
for r_tab in c_tab loop
--                          case: condition sur les data type
case 
when r_tab.data_type in ('VARCHAR2','TIMESTAMP(6)','CHAR','DATE','INTERVAL DAY(9) TO     
SECOND(9)','INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)') then

--                          select du max et min 
v_sql := 'select max('||r_tab.column_name||') from '||r_tab.owner||'.'||r_tab.table_name; 
v_sqln := 'select min('||r_tab.column_name||') from '||r_tab.owner||'.'||r_tab.table_name;
v_vals := null;
--                          affecter les valeur des variables
execute immediate v_sql into v_val;
execute immediate v_sqln into v_valn;
else
--                          select somme
v_sqls := 'select sum('||r_tab.column_name||') from '||r_tab.owner||'.'||r_tab.table_name;
v_val := null;
v_valn := null;
--                          affecter les valeur des variables
execute immediate v_sqls into v_vals;
end case;
--                          count sur toutes les tables
v_sqlz := 'select count(*) from '||r_tab.owner||'.'||r_tab.table_name;
--                          affecter les valeur des variables
execute immediate v_sqlz into v_valz;
--                          query string et trop long ceci pour augmenter la taille du     buffer
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(buffer_size => null);
dbms_output.put_line(r_tab.owner||' : '||r_tab.table_name||' : '||r_tab.column_name||' : '|| v_val||' : '||v_valn||' : '||v_vals||' : '||v_valz||' : '||dat_situ);
--                          enregistrer toutes les données recuperée dans une table   existante dans la base de donnée
insert into MOE_COLMINMAX(owner,table_name,column_name,column_max,column_min,column_sum,num_rows,dat_situ)
values     (r_tab.owner,r_tab.table_name,r_tab.column_name,v_val,v_valn,v_vals,v_valz,dat_situ);
commit;
end loop;
end;
END COMPARAISON_TEST_MINMAX;
```